# Forming extended groups of group elements

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find sql logic of forming extended groups of group elements.

[image]

The first step is to find duplicate keys and get all the elements of the groups containing the duplicate keys. In the example the duplicate keys are Key1 and Key3 from groups G1, G2 and G1, G3. For this duplicate keys, G1 is the same group which merge the groups G2 and G3. The final result need to be new group of all keys from G1, G2 and G3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct `key`
from your_table
where `group` in
(
    select distinct `group`
    from your_table
    where `key` in 
    (
      select `key`
      from your_table
      group by `key`
      having count(*) > 1
    )
)
```

Comment: This query returns the result only from G1: Key1, Key2, Key3. I need to get also the keys from G2 and G3 which are merged by Key1 and Key3.

Comment: The problem is here:
`select group
from your_table
group by key
having count(*) > 1`
which returns just G1 as a result. Expected result would be G1, G2, G3.

Comment: Right, that was a mistake. Can you try again?

Comment: Yes, now is ok. There is a little problem if I had a multiple groups, because with this solutions I only got all groups in the final result and they are not separated.

For example: `G1: k1, k2 ; G2: k2, k3; G3: k4, k5; G4: k5, k6;` Here I need final result: G1G2: k1, k2, k3 ; G3G4: k4, k5, k6. Do you have solution about this? Thank you very much!